# Construction of a probability measure from a sequence of probability measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, mathematical-finance

**Summary**

I would like to pass from a sequence of probability measures whose "limit" satisfies a desired property to a new probability measure that satisfies this property.

**Details**

We work on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $C\subseteq L^{\infty}$ be convex, contain $-L^{\infty}_+$, and be closed in the weak*-topology on $L^{\infty}$.

Suppose there exists a sequence of probability measures $(Q^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, each of which is equivalent to $P$, such that for each $n$,
\begin{equation}
0\leq \sup_{X\in C} E_{Q^n}[X] \leq \frac{1}{n} \enspace (*).
\end{equation}

The goal is to construct a probability measure $Q$, that is equivalent to $P$, such that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{X\in C} E_{Q}[X] =0.
\end{equation*}

**Question**

The *intuitive idea* is to take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ in $(*)$. How can this be formalized? I.e. how can the probability measures $(Q^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be used to construct a new probability measure $Q$ with the desired properties? Are there any papers with a similar construction?

Comment: What do you mean by equivalence for probability measures?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Two probability measures $P,Q$ are equivalent if $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q$ and vice versa. $P$ absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q$ means that $Q[A]=0$ for $A\in\mathcal{F}$ implies $P[A]=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$This is impossible to do in such generality.

E.g., suppose that $\Omega=\R$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\R$, $P$ is the standard normal distribution,
$$C=\{g\in L^\infty\colon g\le f\},$$
$f$ is the standard normal pdf, and $Q^n$ is the normal distribution with mean $n$ and variance $1$.

Then $Q^n$ is equivalent to $P$ for each $n$ and
\begin{equation}
0\le\sup_{X\in C} E_{Q^n}X= E_{Q^n}f
=\int_\R f(t)f(t-n)\,dt
=\frac1{\sqrt2}f\Big(\frac n{\sqrt2}\Big)\le\frac1n
\end{equation}
for each $n$.
However, for any probability measure $Q$ (even if not equivalent to $P$),
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{X\in C} E_Q X=E_Q f>0,
\end{equation*}
since $f>0$.

Comment: Thank you for providing this counterexample. However, in my situation there is the additional assumption that $C\cap L^{\infty}_+ =\{0\}$ (which I did not provide in the description before, but added now). Are there any results you know which treat this problem under more assumptions?

Comment: @hannah : You should not add assumptions that invalidate a valid answer. Such modified questions should be posted separately, not necessarily on MathOverflow. So, I suggest you restore your original, fully answered question, and let us have a closure here.

Comment: I posted the modified question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365841/construction-of-a-probability-measure-from-a-sequence-of-probability-measures. Nevertheless, in case you know any results which treat similar problems, I would appreciate it if you could share them.